# recaptcha does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded

Tags: symfony, recaptcha

I have a project installed on my windows , and today i need to install on a Ubuntu server. The project is saved on an svn sever. so i just use co to check out the project and update all the vendor bundles. all is ok when is get to the web/config.php:
     To enhance your Symfony experience, itâ€™s recommended that you fix the following :

```
Install and enable the intl extension.
Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.

* Changes to the php.ini file must be done in "/home/siteadm/common/php/Perso.ini".
```

so when i click 'go to the welcome page',i got :

```
  AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@EWZ\bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\True" in property Acme\...\User::$recaptcha does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

in fact it works well on my locale. The userbunle usring recapchaBundle and FOSUserbundle, they all works well on my local windows machine.

i check the /vendor directory: they are 755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is not case sensitive. Linux is.

Maybe you should use

> @EWZ\ **Bundle** \RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\True

instead of

> @EWZ\ **bundle** \RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints\Tru3

?

It's very common mistake.

Comment: You save my life. I trying to figure it out and do a research on the old server, which have 4 version of PHP and 40 website on it. it contains more than 20 php-fpm running. I'm Totally losted.